# LINQ select new with collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

#### Context

I am trying to get a list from `select new`:

```
var portfolioresult = 
    (from port in _context.Portfolio
    join u in _context.Universe on port.CUSIP equals u.ID_CUSIP
    join m in _context.MarketDataEvent on u.ID_CUSIP equals m.CUSIP_NUMBER_REALTIME
    //select new { m, port.Name }).ToList();
    select new ViewResult() { MarketDataEvents = m, PortfolioName = port.Name })
    .ToList();
```

I want to get `MarketDataEvents` as `List<MarketDataEvent>`

#### Corresponding SQL query

```sql
SELECT me.*, p.Name FROM MarketDataEvent me
INNER JOIN universe u ON u.ID_CUSIP=me.CUSIP_NUMBER_REALTIME
INNER JOIN portfolio p ON p.CUSIp=me.CUSIP_NUMBER_REALTIME
```

#### Problem

I am not able to get a List inside `select new`. Is it possible to get something like this?

```
select new ViewResult() { MarketDataEvents = List<MarketDataEvents>, PortfolioName = port.Name })
```

#### Expected result

```
List<MarketDataEvents>          "XYZ"
List<MarketDataEvents>          "ABC"
```

#### Actual result

```
MarketDataEvent          "XYZ
MarketDataEvent          "XYZ"
MarketDataEvent          "ABC"
```

Comment: `I am not able to get as List collection from inside select new` what is the error?

Comment: No error I am trying to get List<MarketDataEvents>,portname .Its giving as each  MarketDataEvent I need to have ````{MarketDataEvents = List<MarketDataEvent>, PortfolioName = port.Name ````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```cs
var query = 
    from port in _context.Portfolio
    select new ViewResult
    {
        MarketDataEvents = 
            (from u in _context.Universe.Where(u => port.CUSIP == u.ID_CUSIP)
            join m in _context.MarketDataEvent on u.ID_CUSIP equals m.CUSIP_NUMBER_REALTIME
            select m).ToList(), 
        PortfolioName = port.Name 
    };

var portfolioresult = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi thanks tried If i put comma after select m).ToList() and tried getting compile error Implicit typed varaibles cannot have multiple delcarators.

Comment: So, you cannot fix compiler errors?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your `m` reference is out of scope. The input available to a select statement is only a single value out of the set available as a result of the select/joins you're looking at, which is why you don't see a list of all available from `m`, only a single value in each record.

Rather, you need to use a SelectMany since it'll expose an IEnumerable as the input to the function and you can split out the individual XYZ values out of that.